# Google service account and quotas for admin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

As I'm completing the migration to the new API I stumbled on the daily API request quotas.  What determines quota limits for admin requests? My application provisions accounts, groups, etc... in Google apps and I've got many locations using it.

Do I need to set up a unique service account and certificate for each install of my application or is the quota based on the admin account for the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API quota is based on the application and which will be reset daily at 00:00 AM PST.

Its always better to have unique service account for each application. So that one of the application need more API quote, you can request for that.

Each request to the Google API will be counted. You can monitor your quota details from Google Developer Console.

`APIs & Auth -> APIs -> Select the API -> Navigate to Quota tab`. Here you can view the Quota summary.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious about that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up a unique service account and certificate for each application installed. However, you can request for additional quota.